# Allow others to use a server-to-server IPsec connection

Tags: networking, routing

I have an issue concerning secure IPsec connection between two servers over the internet. One belongs to us and lives in our data-centre, and one belongs to them.

I need to somehow let members of my company to use that secure connection to connect to their server, as their server only allows connections coming from our server.

Our server is running Linux.

A VERY important point is that I have no control of the software that is trying to make the connections (some Citrix Receiver nonsense, launched by a link from a website). It will try to make a direct connection to their server's IP address. Since it is launched by a link which configures it, I cannot, from what I can tell, go in an set a proxy for it to use.

Also, this software will be installed on both Macs and Windows machines, so I need something that will work for both.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the IPsec changed from a /32 to an appropriate subnet sized config, like /24.  You should not try to find ways to compromise an existing tunnel to do something it's not configured for.

Comment: As I said, I can't do anything like that. I have to somehow tunnel/proxy/NAT/something through to it. We're dealing with a big telco monstrosity, they're not going to change their policies just for us.

Comment: If you're a customer, you could get them to create a new site-to-site VPN.  Unless these is some weird setup where you guys are using things in a manner it wasn't designed.  In that case, you should consider migrating to a solution that better fits your needs.

Comment: Well this is life, sometimes we have to make kludges to fit the decisions of managers.

Comment: True, but there's a difference between band-aids and circumventing a process in place.  If you're not careful, the hosting companies that manage your services might see this as a breach and take action or you could find yourself in charge of managing a rats nest that'll add more and more risk to the company.  As server-to-server VPN is meant for 1-to-1 connection.  You need to relay that to your management or the hosting company that the situation/requirement has changed.  Any custom built solution you come up with only comes with more risk and complexity to further make your situation worse.

Answer (score 0):

I THINK I have found a way to do this.

Using OpenVPN, I create a network between the user's machine and our server. (I have to configure it to only route the relevant traffic, not everything like it currently does.)

I set up some iptables rules to source-nat all traffic to their server's IP address so it thinks it is coming from our server. The traffic is automatically sent over the existing IPsec tunnel.

I am not happy with this solution, for obvious reasons. But it works.